# HTaccess - Trailing slash + .php + anchors (ExpressionEngine)

Tags: .htaccess, expressionengine

I just started a project from another webmaster work (i hate patching other's stuff ::sad::) and i have some issues. First we are on expression engine 1.x .

My problem: There is a trailing slash redirection in the .HTACCESS, but my users need to have access to only one .php page (*www.mydomain.com/mobile/index.php*) but the link is redirected to **/index.php/**, another problem is the anchors are changed to the same way (*www.mydomain.com/somepage/#anchor1*) to **/#anchor1/**

So my question is... there is a way to put exception into trailing slash redirection code? I mean i just have to fix it in few pages.  Take note that our expression engine remove all the index.php to have links like www.mydomaine/contact/, www.mydomaine/about/, www.mydomaine/infos/ , ect.

Currently the htaccess trailling code is :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

P-S: we have a code that remove index.php too:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(members|P[0-9]{2,8}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thx for help!

Answer (score 1):

**Is there a valid reason trailing slashes in URLs *need to be enforced?*** If not, I would just remove the rewrite rule and your problem is solved :)

Most ExpressionEngine URLs will work with *or* without trailing slashes.

The easiest fix to this problem would be remove the overzealous trailing slash redirection, and replace it with a more relaxed version:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Enable Apache's RewriteEngine
    RewriteEngine On

    # Add Trailing Slashes to URLs
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

    # ExpressionEngine Remove index.php from URLs
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Using the above code, `example.com/mobile/index.php` **will not get rewritten** to `example.com/mobile/index.php/`, nor will pages with anchors `example.com/page/#anchor1`.

EE doesn't know the difference between URIs like `/mobile` versus `/mobile/`, web analytics apps and search engines may consider these separate web pages. If you're developing a static website, this isn't a big deal, because if you attempt to go to the former URI (sans trailing slash), Apache will automatically redirect the client to the latter (with trailing slash).

But for a web application like EE, where everything in the URI after `index.php` is handled by the *application* rather than *Apache*, this redirection is left up to you. Just like the decision to use or not use a `www` subdomain, it doesn't matter whether you choose to force a trailing slash or vise-versa; it just matters that you enforce one or the other.

> *Sidenote: in EE1, trailing slashes are generated in URLs produced by
>   ExpressionEngine; in EE2, trailing slashes are not generated. The exception
>   is the [Structure Module](http://www.buildwithstructure.com/), which outputs URLs with trailing slashes
>   in both EE1 and EE2*.